# How do I get the handle to a comment element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a side project at work which requires me to write some javascript code. Unfortunately I'm very new to the javascript world and am learning as I go.

So part of what I have to do requires me to find certain comments on the page, and I am using the following line to get all the comments first:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
```

This works perfectly in IE8 and returns an array of all the comments on the page. However this returns an empty array in Google Chrome and I can see an uncaught `TypeError` (Presumably due to operations being performed on the empty array) when I open up the Developer Console.

Any ideas why this is not working on both browsers? Is this some sort of unsupported operation that I shouldn't be using, or am I just misusing it?

Any help, or pointers in some direction are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Clarification:
I am doing this in order to manipulate a sharepoint page. That actual intent of this script is to hide a table row that an input element is in. So to do that I need to first find the element, but I can't do that since the attributes for it are basically garbled junk:

```
<input name="ctl00$m$g_edc51673_bad2_46d5_9a65_e71137e56558$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl‌​00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$TextField"
type="text" value="Title" maxlength="255"
id="ctl00_m_g_edc51673_bad2_46d5_9a65_e71137e56558_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_‌​ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField"
title="Title" class="ms-long">
```

(I put in newlines in some places to make it easier to read, but that's all on one line in the source (not that that makes a difference))

So anyway, I can't really use that find the control I'm looking for. And you may say that that has some structure what with the type of the input consistently at the end of the garbage, and the title attribute and all that. But it isn't. Yours truly, Microsoft, does this for some controls, but not for others.

BUT! They are absolutely consistent with providing comments right before this garbled junk that have the name of the element in them, and if I can grab that comment I can foo.parenNode over to what I want.

Comment: Comments aren't tags, let along elements, even if Microsoft think they are.

Comment: So this is just IE goofing up as usual? Is there any other way for me to grab the comments then?

Comment: Why do you want to "grab" comments?  If you've got content that's actually important to the page, why wouldn't it be in real tags?

Comment: @Pointy: added a clarification to explain why I can't use the "real tags."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can traverse the DOM starting at the node, `document` and iterating each node's `childNodes` array.    When you find a node, you can test for the `nodeType==8`

Here are links to

[childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes)

[nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)

[document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createTextNode)

And a small example

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>junk
<li>text
<!-- comment 1 -->
<li>hi
<li>hello
<li>world
</ul>
<br/>
<!-- comment 2 -->
<script>
window.onload=findcommentsstart
var msgs = [];
function findcommentsstart()
{
    findcomments(document);
    var txt = document.createTextNode(msgs.join("\n"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(txt);
}

function findcomments(d)
{
    if(!d)
        return;
    if(d.nodeType==8)
        msgs.push("found a comment node " + d.data);
    if(!d.childNodes)
        return;
    for(var i=0;i<d.childNodes.length;i++)
        findcomments(d.childNodes[i]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a clarification question. What does the `if(!d)` statement check for?

Comment: `if(!d)` just makes sure that d is defined before trying to check the nodeType property or the childNodes property...I was probably being paranoid about checking d there, but it doesn't break anything :)

Comment: If you grab the node from the parent's childNodes array aren't you guaranteed to have a valid node? ..and also thus making you correct in saying that it was probably just you being paranoid. :] Also, do you know if there is possibly a faster way to do this rather than traversing the entire document tree?

Comment: Technically speaking, some other JS code in a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` could call `removeChild()` on some element after a call to findcomments but just before the `d.childNodes[i]`

Comment: ahh, okay. That's interesting. As I said in the question, I'm learning JavaScript on the fly here so even such small clarifications help on the way! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could avoid this by loading the page in a String variable (e.g. using AJAX) and parsing it.

I would say ignoring comments should be the desired behaviour, beacuse comments should be considered a "no-go" for the parser/interpreter.

IE is always doing some fancy (non-standard) stuff which often breaks things ;)