# Javascript replace portion of innerHTML for template engine

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am writing a template engine. I am trying to update certain parts of the innerHTML on demand, for instance when the model updates.

I could update portions in two ways as far as I have discovered:

1. Wrap the html portion with a parent element, fetch that element and regenerate the contents of it and reinsert. Wrapping might however break css rules and what not, and will modify the users current html structure.
2. Put a comment before and after, discover what the portion to be updated is, and then replace that exact portion. This is working fine, but when I then do:

   `document.documentElement.innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, indexStart) + template + innerHTML.substring(indexEnd);`

The entire dom is replaced with a new string and all event bindings from other parts will be lost.

So does anyone have a better idea of how I can replace only a portion of the html using the comment strategy or similar strategy?

**Example**:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div>something</div>

    <!-- id:321312321 -->
      <div>Replace all within this comment space</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    <!-- id:321312321 -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats totally irrelevant... lets just say that you'l know when I release it...

Comment: Not really. You can check out some of the 10s of template engines on github to see how they did it or just not bother and use a true and tested one

Comment: they all suck, thats why ... please .. you can go back and use prototype or css2 if you like ... the world moves on, stick to the question instead, ok?

Comment: typically, people upvote stupid comments assuming that indeed I can't do a better job than what is already currently available or that one shouldn't even attempt to do better, I pity those fools.

Comment: @MoJS: So it looks like your engine is going to have to capture the event bindings and then rebind them once you replace the content, no? If you destroy DOM elements that have events, the only way to get those events back is capture and re-add them to the new elements. You'll have to create a mechanism (or re-use one, such as jQuery's) to maintain events on current and future elements. That said, is your engine going to do something that these can't? http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Comment: Just don't use innerHTML to replace stuff.

Comment: @Cory thanks for a constructive comment. I see, is there a way to look up all the currently active bindings before replacing. Another strategy I found is to do something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594661/get-content-between-comments or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666083/how-do-i-get-the-handle-to-a-comment-element-in-javascript

Comment: @MoJS Please calm down. I assumed that if you have problems with this basic template engine issue that has to have been solved by at least one template engine writing guru worth his salt, then you would not be the one that wrote the template engine to surpass all template engines :) - You answered my question: they all suck. So thanks for that

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that would mean finding the elements between the comments node using the dom rather than text indexof on innerhtml ... I found some threads I will look into ...

Comment: @MoJS: personally I would suggest researching everything the top 10 existing JavaScript templating engines can do. If you'd like to add functionality to those, most of them are open-source. You can use their code as a base to build upon -- or, more than likely, you can write a plugin or extension to those templating engines that add the functionality you desire without needed to modify their cores. I only suggest that because a lot of them have already worked out the thousands of kinks and differences between browsers, so your time-to-deliver drops drastically.

Comment: @Cory I have already done that, handlebars being the best but also so limited that its not really an option for the future of Javascript client based applications. My library is already written, but there is no documentation yet. This is just the last feature to add on top of it. I gurantee you that this will be the best template engine out there once it is released. I will get back to you all to prove my point in a couple of weeks time.

Comment: @mplungjan This is just a typical answer that I have to deal with on a constant basis. People diverge and try to solve your problems by suggesting something else that is not an answer to the question. I should never have mentioned that I am writing a template engine, but if I didn't people would still wonder why I even want to do this. I have my reasons. Thats all.

Comment: @MoJS: My first reaction is that maybe you're attempting to do something that constitutes *more* than just a templating engine. I'm not saying you shouldn't write your own -- it's great that you are exploring that route -- I think we just wanted to make sure you have expored the *other* routes as well.

Comment: Good luck, I will be looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: I have added an answer for those that want to know how it was achieved finally

Answer (score 0):

**Can be used on example:**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>something</div>

    <!-- id:321312321 -->
      <div>Replace all within this comment space</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    <!-- id:321312321 -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**as:**

```
commentReplaceBetween("<div>1</div>", " id:321312321 ");
```

**will result in:**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>something</div>

    <!-- id:321312321 -->
    <div>1</div>
    <!-- id:321312321 -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**code:**

```
function commentReplaceBetween(template, commentContent) {
        var div       = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = template;

        // Find our comment first
        var comment    = nodeCommentFind(document.documentElement, commentContent);
        var parentNode = comment.parentNode;
        var sibling    = comment.nextSibling;

        // Delete all contents in between
        while ( sibling ) {
                if ( nodeCommentContentMatch(sibling, commentContent) ) {
                        break;
                } else {
                        var tmp = sibling;
                        sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
                        parentNode.removeChild(tmp);
                }
        }

        // Then append our elements afterw
        var child, children  = div.childNodes;
        for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                child = children[i];

                // See:
                // http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml
                // and
                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764649(v=vs.85).aspx
                if ( child.nodeType === 1 || child.nodeType === 7 || child.nodeType === 8 || child.nodeType === 11 ) {
                        // Sibling here should be the last comment, otherwise the entire page have been incorrectly deleted.
                        parentNode.insertBefore(child, sibling);
                }
        }
}

var cacheComment = {};
function nodeCommentFind(node, commentContent) {
        var child = cacheComment[commentContent];
        if ( child ) {
                return child;
        }
        else {
                return nodeCommentFindRecurse(node, commentContent);
        }
}

function nodeCommentFindRecurse(node, commentContent) {
        var children = node.childNodes;

        var child, returns;
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                child = children[i];

                if( nodeCommentContentMatch(child, commentContent) ) {
                        cacheComment[commentContent] = child;
                        return child;
                }
                else if ( child.hasChildNodes && child.childNodes ) {
                        returns = nodeCommentFindRecurse(child, commentContent);
                        if ( returns ) return returns;
                }
        }
}

function nodeCommentIs(node) {
        return node.nodeType === 8;
}
function nodeCommentContentMatch(node, commentContent) {
        return nodeCommentIs(node) && node.nodeValue === commentContent;
}
```

---

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////// BONUS INFORMATION ////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**My commentReplaceBetween is called like this though**

```
commentReplaceBetween(commentContent)(template);
```

**So my actual commentReplaceBetween function is wrapped and look like this:**

```
function commentReplaceBetween(commentContent) {
        return function(template) {
                var div       = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = template;

                // Find our comment first
                var comment    = nodeCommentFind(document.documentElement, commentContent);
                var parentNode = comment.parentNode;
                var sibling    = comment.nextSibling;

                // Delete all contents in between
                while ( sibling ) {
                        if ( nodeCommentContentMatch(sibling, commentContent) ) {
                                break;
                        } else {
                                var tmp = sibling;
                                sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
                                parentNode.removeChild(tmp);
                        }
                }

                // Then append our elements afterw
                var child, children  = div.childNodes;
                for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                        child = children[i];

                        // See:
                        // http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml
                        // and
                        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764649(v=vs.85).aspx
                        if ( child.nodeType === 1 || child.nodeType === 7 || child.nodeType === 8 || child.nodeType === 11 ) {
                                // Sibling here should be the last comment, otherwise the entire page have been incorrectly deleted.
                                parentNode.insertBefore(child, sibling);
                        }
                }
        };
}
```