# Find comments with js

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i have this code for finding 1st comment:

```
for (var i = 0, node; node = document.childNodes[0].childNodes[i]; i++) {    
    if (node.nodeType === 8) {
        alert(node.nodeValue)
    }
}
```

this works fine in chrome it doesn't work in ie. It doesn't alert anything.
So how to make it work?

Comment: How does that loop stop?

Comment: when document.childNodes[0].childNodes[i] = undefined it stops

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')

var comments = divs.filter(function (div) { return div.nodeType === 8;});
```

Comment: `<head></head><!-- comment text -->
<body>` this doesn't work in this situation wherecomment is not div

Comment: Well, there is here an elaborated question, I guess it will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666083/how-do-i-get-the-handle-to-a-comment-element-in-javascript